# Get Enums by Index relation in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum UserRole {
  Admin = 1,
  Leader = 2,
  Editor = 3,
  Guest = 4
} // UserRole
```

And the following list:

```
IList<UserRole> roles = new List<UserRole> { UserRole.Leader, UserRole.Editor };
```

I would like to create two new lists:

1 - A list that picks the lowest index item in roles, eg, UserRole.Leader = 2 and all the UserRoles higher than that one. So I would get:

```
UserRole.Leader, UserRole.Editor, UserRole.Guest
```

2 - A list that picks the highest index item in roles, eg, UserRole.Editor = 3 and all the UserRoles lower than that one. So I would get:

```
UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Leader, UserRole.Editor
```

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
public enum UserRole
{
    Admin = 1,
    Leader = 2,
    Editor = 3,
    Guest = 4
}

IList<UserRole> roles = new List<UserRole> { UserRole.Leader, UserRole.Editor };

var min = roles.Min();

var max = roles.Max();

var result1 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)).Cast<UserRole>()
                  .Where(x => x >= min);

var result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)).Cast<UserRole>()
                 .Where(x => x <= max);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate the enum using `Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)));` so the answer would be:

```
IList<UserRole> GetHigherRoles(UserRole role)
{
    var roles = new List<UserRole>();
    foreach (var r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)))
    {
        if ((UserRole)r >= role)
        {
            roles.Add((UserRole)r);
        }
    }
    return roles;
}

IList<UserRole> GetLowerRoles(UserRole role)
{
    var roles = new List<UserRole>();
    foreach (var r in Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole)))
    {
        if ((UserRole)r <= role)
        {
            roles.Add((UserRole)r);
        }
    }
    return roles;
}
```